# WifiP2pManager null

Tags: android, null, wifip2p

I'm getting mad, i'm following this tutorial on Wifi peer to peer :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

To find the error, I tried many things in `onCreate()` in my activity and my last test was just that :

```
WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
manager.toString();
```

I found out that my manager is always null. I don't understand why, my API's level is correct and I don't find any problems about `WifiP2pManager` and `getSystemService` on Internet. What I missed ?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Each time I ran the code through the emulator I received an error message that the object was null, but when I ran the code in my Nexus (real device) there was no error and the object is not null. In my opinion the reason is that the emulator does not support p2p and the real device yes. Hope I helped.